# I can't delete flutter project using flutter clean , rm -rf build , flutter build clean

Tags: flutter

i can't delete flutter project by using any above code. it is showing ..

```
flutter clean
```

"Failed to remove build: FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path = 'build' (OS
Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)
Deleting build...                                                   14ms
Failed to remove /media/a/8C76232376230D90/code/flutter/tryFlutter/.dart_tool:
FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path =
'/media/a/8C76232376230D90/code/flutter/tryFlutter/.dart_tool' (OS Error:
Read-only file system, errno = 30)
Deleting .dart_tool...                                               2ms
Failed to remove

```
 rm -rf build
```

"rm: cannot remove 'build/cache.dill.track.dill': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove 'build/kotlin/sessions': Read-only file system"

```
flutter build clean
```

"Could not find a subcommand named "clean" for "flutter build".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter commands and
options."

Comment: try with sudo rm -rf

Comment: tried this, but not working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod 777  -R  /build   

sudo rm -rf build
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your answer to include a description of what your code does.

Comment: Also, when recommending things that have security implications (like completely opening up permissions) or that could badly wreak havoc if mistyped (like `sudo rm -rf`), please always include clear warnings.